# Qlik data integration (Replicate & Compose) certification questions

Tags: qlikview

If you have taken the Qlik data integration (Replicate & Compose) certification. Please share some of the questions asked? I would do with some revision questions. The documentation is very lengthy, and I am yet to use the tool. Thanks.

I am trying to get sample Qlik replicate and compose questions online, but to no avail.